# Different form ACTION depending on button pressed

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form and I would like the ACTION field to be different depending on the button pressed.

For instance the form might get processed by different PHP files if I press button A or button B.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your buttons you can just set the form's action, using it's [`form` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533768(v=VS.85).aspx), for example on button a:

```
this.form.action = "fileA.php";
```

On the other:

```
this.form.action = "fileB.php";
```

You can rig this up externally, like this:

```
document.getElementById("buttonA").onclick = function() { 
  document.getElementById("myForm").action = "fileA.php";
};
```

Or if you're using a library like jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $("#buttonA").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("form").attr('action', 'fileA.php');
  });
});
```

Comment: Can I combine the POST and GET methods? For instance, I want to pass a URL containing fields but also the form elements by their names.

Comment: @posfan12 - You can only submit via one method at a time, though you could serialize and post to a url with params.  I'm not following you on why you would ever need to have both though, it's more data for the client to send as well and generally not a great idea.

Comment: You can have both POST and GET at the same time. When you add parameters to the url with '?' and '&' they will become the GET and if you have also POST parameters defined they will be in the POST at the same request.

Answer (score 33):

If you don't want to use Javascript, but do use HTML5, you can use the attribute `formaction`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="submit" formaction="http://firsttarget.com" value="Submit to first" />
      <input type="submit" formaction="http://secondtarget.com" value="Submit to second" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Best solution by a longshot.

Comment: Big thanks! Works perfectly.. we can use `formtarget="_blank"` also to open new tab

Answer (score 1):

Leave the action field blank:

```
<form action ="" method="post" name="form1">
<input type ="submit" onclick="calA();"/>
<input type = "submit" onclick="calB"/>
</form>

<script>
function calA()
{
 document.form1.action ="a.php";
}
function calB()
{
document.form1.action = "b.php";
}
</script>
```