# HTML Form action no reaction

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

this is a newbie question, but I don't know how to do.
I have a form , but have two submit button
and two action all no reaction.
this is my view:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
輸入金額*：<input type="text" name="txtmoney" id="txtmoney" value="" required/><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="moneyout" id="moneyout" value="提款" action="/app_dev.php/bank/moneyout"/>
<input type="submit" name="moneyin" id="moneyin" value="存款" action="/app_dev.php/bank/moneyin"/>
<input type="reset" name="btnReset" id="btnReset" value="重填金額"/></div><br>
</form>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/action

Comment: Dupes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661645/change-form-action-based-on-submit-button  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753308/different-form-action-depending-on-button-pressed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to specify the action in the submit buttons, you have to use the `formaction` attribute, not `action`.

```
<input type="submit" name="moneyout" id="moneyout" value="提款" formaction="/app_dev.php/bank/moneyout"/>
<input type="submit" name="moneyin" id="moneyin" value="存款" formaction="/app_dev.php/bank/moneyin"/>
```

Comment: Dupe anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753308/different-form-action-depending-on-button-pressed