# In form: Submit different button to transfer to different page (html)

Tags: html, forms

my current code:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Select button </h1>

<form method="get">

  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>

Choose your page when submit:
<button name="subject" type="submit" value="aa">Page A</button>
<button name="subject" type="submit" value="bb">Page B</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

How can i make codiontion for flow :
click button "page A" redirect to "http://linkA" or
click button "page B" to redirect to "http://linkB"

Thank you

Comment: Don't make a submit button. Submit buttons are to submit forms. Not to redirect to another page. Use a normal button and redirect with Javascript using a click event handler.

Comment: Create two forms.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753308/different-form-action-depending-on-button-pressed/46246125#46246125

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different form ACTION depending on button pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753308/different-form-action-depending-on-button-pressed)

Answer (score 0):

You have many options:

1. Use a regular link, and style it like a button in CSS
2. Use Javascript: onclick="window.location='TARGET';"
3. Put each submit button in its own form with different action parameter
4. Use formaction HTML attribute (Use This!)

```
<form method="get" action="pageA">    
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
    
    Choose your page when submit:
    <button name="subject" type="submit" value="aa">Page A</button>
    <button name="subject" type="submit" value="bb" formaction="/pageB">Page B</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please help and more detail for option 3. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try to using this custom code

Html Code

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Select button </h1>

<form method="get" id="form-one" action="">
<form method="get" id="form-two" action="" style="display:none">

  <button name="subject" type="submit" id="button-one" value="aa">Page A</button>
  <button name="subject" type="submit" id="button-two" value="bb">Page B</button>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript Code

```
 $("#button-one").click(function(){
      $('#form-one').show();
      $('#form-two').hide();
});

$("#button-two").click(function(){
    $('#form-one').hide();
    $('#form-two').show();
});
```